kotlin тесты с companion object не работают при тестировании пакета целиком
Только перехожу с java на kotlin.
В моих тетах есть конструкции
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MyTest {
//
 @Test
 fun 'test 1'(){
  //
 }
 //
 companion object{
  const val CONST=//
 }
}

При запуске тестов для конкретного класса
gradle :myProject:test --tests "ru.my.MyTest"

то все ок, все работае
Но если я запускаю тесты для пакета, то все падает
gradle :myProject:test --tests "ru.my.*"

Прием воспринимает companion как класс и ругается на него
- Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor 
- No runnable methods

Как это поправить. Не могу сделать билд за этого
